# Angular2 webpack raw!sass loaders with UglifyJS issue

Tags: angular, webpack, uglifyjs, sass-loader, raw-loader

I use webpack to configure my angular2 application bundles.

I use sass to design the pages.

The loaders chain to resolve the sass for the component style is:`raw!sass`

When I use it with for development without minification it works all fine.

When I use the UglifyJS plugin it breaks the design, what I see it changes the class positions on imported css class.

My component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navigation-bar',
  template: require('./navigation.component.html'),
  styles: [require('./navigation.component.scss')],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavigationComponent {
}
```

My webpack config for styles:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap')
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
    loader: 'raw!sass'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!resolve-url!css?sourceMap')
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
    loader: 'raw!resolve-url'
  }
```

The scss file:

```
@import "../../../../commonStyles/_colors";
@import '../../../../../../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min';

nav{
  @extend .blue;

  .brand-logo{
    @extend .left;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }

  .navigation-options {
    @extend .right;

    .dropdown-button{
      padding: 0;

      i{
        padding-left: 1rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
      }
    }

    .dropdown-content{
      width: auto;

      li{
        a{
          @extend .blue-text;

          i.material-icons{
            display: inline;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: 1rem;
          }

          .text{
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

When I use the UglifyJS it messes up with the order of the classes that come from the materialize library.

If I compile the scss file and require the css file it works just fine, but this way if I change something in the `_colors.scss` file I will need to compile the scss file myself because the webpack doesn't know to look for it.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have gotten solution then can you check the question I am getting like same issue there stackoverflow.com/questions/49818744